# How to capture that session logoff started from windows service

Tags: c++, windows, service, logoff

I have a service which constantly checks some application and assures that it wasn't closed. If this app closed - service launches it again.

The problem starts when user decides to log off the session. During logoff all applications are closing including the mine one. But the service is still running and constantly trying to start it again.

The questions is how to notify the service that user is going to log off and the application doesn't need to be restarted anymore? I've tried to make it using SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE notification. But in accordance to MSDN they come to services when all apps already closed and logging off procedure completed. It is too late for me. Is there any way to programmatically find out that current session is in process of logging off?

My service launched under LocalSystem account.

Thanks.

p.s. I don't have the access to application source code. The goal need to be achieved without modifying it.

Comment: Why don't you just make your app (at least the part that should always run) a service?

Comment: "My app" is an application I need to run constantly. But it is not written by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your service run two applications: the one it is a watchdog for, and a second one which you implement yourself.  This second one can then respond to the log-off event by sending a message to the service (a la David Heffernan's answer), and the service will then know not to restart the watched job.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking on this solution but it doesn't seem to be "tidy". I'd better avoid having unnecessary application running constantly.

Comment: @vkjr If you don't have control of the app then you may need to accept some untidiness

Comment: @David Only if there are no other ways.

Comment: There are always other ways.  At some level what you are trying to accomplish is fundamentally messy and broken (we could dig into why you need to constantly monitor and restart a program running in a user session), so I humbly suggest you implement something and move on to better things.

Answer (score 0):

Open a communication channel between your app and your service and arrange for the app to tell the service that it is closing because of a logoff event.

Comment: Thanks for the proposal. Unfortunately this way works only if you are the author of the application. In my case I need to keep running the app which is 3rd party.

Comment: This must be a really special app! What is it? Could you turn it into a service with something like srvany?

Comment: I don't have an access to this app :) My customer didn't provide it so I'm testing the service using notepad.exe instead :) Unless there is no other way I'd better solve the problem using only service functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have access to the source code of the *executable*, but that doesn't mean that you can't affect the *process*. For instance, you could [inject a DLL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection). Using `SetWindowsHookEx`, you'd catch the `WM_ENDSESSION` sent to the apps main window.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create your service under the user that is running the App and tell it to startup automatic? In this case you should get the SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN message when your user is logging off since the service would also be terminated.

Comment: Service doesn't receive SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN if system is logging off. Only if it shuts down.

Comment: I thought that if you setup a service to start when user logs on and stop when user logs off you'd get the SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP and after that the SHUTDOWN command. At least that's what i experienced when stopping my services manually (never tried on logoff since our use case does not support logging off).

Comment: I've experienced only SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP receiving but anyway it is too late for me, applications already closed at receiving moment. So I'm going to proceed with the way @JohnZwinck mentioned.